# Im trying to turn this black hole project to a obj with texture. But when i do it just has the circle and squares not what i have view port shading

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, shaders, export, obj

I'm trying add my black hole to element 3d but the textures are not carrying over when I make it an obj

Comment: Hello maybe show some screenshots of your material and interface, or share your file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures